# Realm leaves nested ophan objects

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm having a problem with orphan objects using those two simple models below:

**Torrent.swift**

```
final class Torrent: Object {
    @objc dynamic var id: Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var name: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var peers: RLMArray<Peer> = RLMArray(objectClassName: Peer.className())

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

**Peer.swift**

```
final class Peer: Object {
    @objc dynamic var address: String = ""

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "address"
    }
}
```

as you can see `Torrent` has a relationship with `Peer`.

When I try to store `Torrent` `Object`s in Realm using:

```
realm.add(objects, update: true)
```

(where `objects` is a Swift `Array` of `Torrent`s)

Realm correctly updates the `Torrent` database objects with latest values but it keeps previous `Peer`s occurencies in the database, forcing me to perform a query of `Peer.self` `Object`s and deleting all of them manually before writing new data.

*To better explain:*

**Step 1:**
Realm saves a `Torrent` with 20 `Peer`s

**Step 2:**
*Remote call*

**Step 3:**
Realm updates the previous `Torrent` which now has 10 `Peer`s

**Expected result:**
The Realm database should contain 1 `Torrent` and 10 `Peer` in total

**Current result:**
Realm database contains 1 `Torrent` and 20 `Peer`s

Comment: Well Realm doesn't know that your backend doesn't have them, and you didn't tell it that you don't have them. Why do you expect it to suddenly disappear from your database? If you want to delete them, then delete them.

Comment: Because I expected that realm considered the `Torrent`-`Peer` relation when using `realm.add(objects, update: true)` method. What is happening here is that Realm considers `Torrent` and `Peers` unrelated, so one can live without the other

Comment: Unfortunately Realm doesn't do cascade deletion yet, although they are probably going to do it this year